# all_trips scope not returning current trip

Tags: uber-api

I'm prototyping a trip experience. In debug we have a button that requests an in_progress ride to work with. Everything seems to work ok.

However, a release build (hitting the real API rather than sandbox) I get no trips back.

We have requested: request and all_trips scope.
We have the test users' uber accounts added to the developer portal.

Requesting the scopes is working, we're takin to the site and it asks for the appropriate scopes, the app is listed in the user's profile.

Any ideas? Is there a region limitation, for example?

Answer (score 1):

Could you provide some more details on the the exact flow you are following and what endpoints you are hitting?

If you make a GET request to nonsandbox /v1/requests/current with an access token for a user that is on a trip, what response do you get back?

Comment: I authorise (if not authorised already). Then hit GET https://api.uber.com/v1/requests/current periodically (while in the foreground) to check if there is a ride. This is a prototype app. We are looking into experiences.

It works if I request the ride through the sandbox myself. Using the non sandbox api endpoint always returns a 404.

The app is extremely simple. It auths then hits requests/current looking for an in_progress ride.

Comment: Also note: The user on behalf of which I am requesting the current ride is a developer account added to the dashboard for the app.

Comment: Hey Ryan,

So normally if you don't have the all_trips scope and you try to get the current trip of a ride requested through the APP, you'll get a forbidden error, not a 404 so I don't think this is a permissions issue.

Is it possible that the access token you are using is for a different user than the one you're requesting through the APP for?

Comment: The permissions are correct and it's a valid user (added to the dev portal). Our current guess is that the API doesn't work outside of North America. No idea if that's true.

Comment: I don't think thats the issue. I just requested an uber in Brisbane and then was able to get the status of the current trip with the /requests/current endpoint. Is it possible that you're getting an access token for a different user than the one that you're requesting the Uber with? For example, if you have developers A and B on your application and when you get an access token you're getting one for developer A because thats the session in your browser, but you're requesting an Uber through the app with developer B's account?